# Off topic but no appropriate Stack Exchange on list

Tags: support, flags, migration

This question is off topic for Stack Overflow:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382623/what-is-the-disadvantages-of-rooting-you-device.

But, when I try to flag it, Android.SE does not show up on the list.  How come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a moderator-only option.

**Only moderators have access to migrating posts to more than what is shown** in the default list of sites to migrate to.  Flag for moderator attention, and mention the reason and the moderators should take care of it.

Comment: if this is moderators only, what can I do about it? ignore?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention, @silent, and say what site you think it should be on...The mods will take it from there...

Comment: Except that this is **not** a moderator-only option (any more?). I could pick a site with the flag, but only a few are in the list.